# Up-to-date setup for Auth0 in WebAPI 2 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, auth0

I have a project with SPA application on the frontend, and ASP.NET WebAPI 2 project (.NET 4.6.1) in the backend, and trying to setup authentication/authorization using Auth0.

My idea was to have SPA use Auth0 widget to generate the bearer token, and they pass this token back to WebAPI where the authorization steps will be taken based on it.

I followed through the QuickStart for WebAPI 2, which basically has one important setting in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var domain = $"https://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0Domain"]}/";
    var apiIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0ApiIdentifier"];

    var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
                ValidIssuer = domain,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(identifier)
            }
        });

    // Configure Web API
    WebApiConfig.Configure(app);
}
```

However, this project sample seems to be outdated.

Firstly, it fails to compile, because the signature of IssuerSigningKeyResolver has been changed - specifically the ‘identifier’ parameter is no longer of type SecurityKeyIdentifier, but instead a string.

Secondly, if I simply comment out this line, and try to run it, I get exception:

```
Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.DateTimeUtil' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

The versions of the project packages are:

```
Auth0.Owin.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver 1.0.0.0
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt 4.0.0.0
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens 5.2.1.0
```

My question is: does anyone know about the working example of WebAPI 2 QuickStart or maybe some other way to use Auth0 in the scenario described above?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @MatthewHartz Yes - the answer I got from Auth0 support is that this is the problem with MS packages, for which they do not have a solution/workaround. I decided to move to Core WebAPI...integration with Auth0 went smooth there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Microsoft made changes in OWIN 4 that broke the Auth0 Nuget package. When this answer was written, Auth0 is only supporting OWIN 3, see https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/webapi-owin#validate-access-tokens.

Auth0 is working on adding OWIN 4 support, see https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet-owin/issues/60.

I found some code in the Github comment thread that enabled me to get Auth0 to work with OWIN 4 in my project. The following code is from my Startup.cs file.

```
    var domain = $"https://{config.Properties["Auth0Domain"]}/";
    var apiIdentifier = config.Properties["Auth0ApiIdentifier"] as string;
    //var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);
    //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    //    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    //    {
    //        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
    //        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    //        {
    //            ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
    //            ValidIssuer = domain,
    //            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(identifier)
    //        }
    //    });
    var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                domain.TrimEnd('/') + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
                ValidIssuer = domain,
                IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                {
                    var openIdConnectConfig = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    return openIdConnectConfig.SigningKeys;
                }
            }
        });
```

The commented out code is the original Auth0 OWIN sample code. To get this snippet to compile, remove the Auth0.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver NuGet package and the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions NuGet package from your packages.config file, and update the using statements in your Startup.cs file.

Edit: Version 2.0.0 of the Auth0.OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver nuget package supports OWIN 4. Use that package instead of this code.

Comment: Wow. Really helped me a lot. I could see they deprecated, but they did not update the docs properly. There are no examples I could find for API in  .Net Framework